# Select_full_join number that keep increasing

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, mysql-slow-query-log

I'm stuck for a while now, with a Select_full_join number that keep increasing.

I'm using "log-queries-not-using-indexes", I looked at the mysql-slow.log and I found a lot of querys like this one :

```
# Time: 131106 16:44:51
# User@Host: XXX @ localhost []
# Query_time: 0.000497  Lock_time: 0.000061 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1383752691;
SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM 
com_c_jobs_listing cj
WHERE  (category IN  ('Operations', 'Business Development', 'Sales/Account Management', 'R&D', 'Internal IT')) AND (country IN  ('Brazil', 'China', 'France', 'Germany', 'Italy', 'Japan', 'Korea', 'Netherlands', 'Russia', 'United Kingdom', 'United States')) ) subquery;
```

I don't get why this is logged. 
Also, there is an index on both category and country.

I think I missed something but I can't find what...

This is the result of the explain query :

> id     select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
>   1  PRIMARY     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Select tables optimized away
>   2  DERIVED     cj  range   category,country    category    302     NULL    86  Using where

What should I do? Any idea?

Comment: Did you run `EXPLAIN` on your query?

Comment: Yes, I updated the description.
It's using "where" and I think it's ok, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Your outer query has no INDEX as it is on the table created from the derived subquery.

Answer (score 0):

From your explain extended (truncated here):

```
id  select_type possible_keys       key         key_len
1   PRIMARY     NULL                NULL        NULL 
2   DERIVED     category,country    category    302
```

You can see that a key is being selected for the derived subquery, but your parent query is counting on a derived table, so not indexed (no possible keys).

Why did you have a subquery and just not count the rows directly?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM com_c_jobs_listing cj
WHERE  category IN  ('Operations', 
  'Business Development', 'Sales/Account 
  Management', 'R&D', 'Internal IT')
AND country IN  ('Brazil', 'China', 'France', 
  'Germany', 'Italy', 'Japan', 'Korea', 'Netherlands',
  'Russia', 'United Kingdom', 'United States');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `log-queries-not-using-indexes` setting does just that.  It logs queries that aren't using indexes.  However, in order for a query to count towards [`select_full_join`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-status-variables.html), it must be a *join* that causes a full table scan.

While the documentation doesn't explain how to track these queries down, you can query the [`performance_schema.events_statements_history`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-events-statements-current-table.html) table (and it's "current" and "history_long" siblings) to find the actual statements.  The table includes the columns `select_full_join` and `select_full_range_join` which will be non-zero if the query meets those criteria.  The `sql_text` column will contain the SQL itself and `current_schema` will tell you the database it was run in.

It should be noted that the performance_schema event tables don't track every query from everywhere, so you may need to query the table regularly until you find your culprit.  See the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-event-tables.html) for further details.